# how do I scrape the pictures from hidden div class?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape all the pictures from a listing on one website.
Since I've been practicing scraping (with python) from time to time, I thought I could do it without any issue but the problem was that I could only scrape first 2 pictures even though there were more than those. Below is my code and the different outputs I've got from first 2 pictures and from 3rd pictures.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#go to the webpage.
page=urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g32655-d4751024-West_HOLLYWD_area_FAB-Los_Angeles_California.html")

#parse html
soup=BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")    
time.sleep(3)

#check the length of the listings if it matches the number of pictures.
images=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__imageGallerySlide--3HC1k"})
print (len(images))

#get the first 2 pictures.
for i in range(0,2,1):
    images=soup.findAll("img", {"class":"media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__isLandscape--3tIc2"})
    each_image=images[i]    
    each_image_detail=each_image["src"]

    print (each_image_detail)

#The outputs:
#58
#https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/00/26/29/8c.jpg
#https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/12/01.jpg
```

Since there were 58 pictures for this listing, I could notice that the length of images was 58. But when I increase the range from 2 to 3, I saw an error, IndexError: list index out of range. So I scraped the outer div class for 1st,2nd, and 3rd pictures to see what had happened.

```
images=soup.findAll("div", {"class":"media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__imageGallerySlide--3HC1k"})
print (images[0])
print (images[1])
print (images[2])

#The outputs:
<div class="media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__imageGallerySlide--3HC1k" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(0%, 0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0%, 0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(0%, 0, 0);-o-transform:translate3d(0%, 0, 0);transform:translate3d(0%, 0, 0)"><div class="media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__carouselImage--SYdol"><img alt="Redwood Deck with tables, umbrella, chaise lounges" class="media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__isLandscape--3tIc2" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/00/26/29/8c.jpg"/></div></div>
<div class="media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__imageGallerySlide--3HC1k" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0);-o-transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0);transform:translate3d(100%, 0, 0)"><div class="media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__carouselImage--SYdol"><img alt="Living Room" class="media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__isLandscape--3tIc2" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/12/01.jpg"/></div></div>
<div class="media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__imageGallerySlide--3HC1k" style="-webkit-transform:translate3d(200%, 0, 0);-moz-transform:translate3d(200%, 0, 0);-ms-transform:translate3d(200%, 0, 0);-o-transform:translate3d(200%, 0, 0);transform:translate3d(200%, 0, 0)"></div>
```

I don't understand why some parts of div class are missing from 3rd. When I right-click and inspect the 3rd pictures, I can see the exact same structure as what I can see from 1st and 2nd. Could anyone help me out how I can scrape from 3rd pictures to the last number of the pictures for a listing?

p.s. Is it allowed to post actual websites and a few lines of actual source code here? I tried to be specific to explain the issue but if it's not allowed to write down the actual outputs, I'll delete those right away.

Thank you.

Comment: You are looking for different classes: `media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__imageGallerySlide--3HC1k` and `media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__isLandscape--3tIc2`. From the later there are obviously only two.

Comment: @Daniel Hi, Daniel. Yes. It's true that there are only two from the 3rd. But when I right-clicked and inspected the 3rd pic, I could not only see the 3rd ```media-media-carousel-MediaCarousel__isLandscape--3tIc2``` but also it has the same html structure as 1st and 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the images in `<img>` tags, the page adds them dynamically via Javascript. BeautifulSoup cannot help you here, because it doesn't execute Javascript.

You can however use some other libraries, like `selenium` for example. Or you can use `re` and parse the desired data from page itself. This should give you an example:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/VacationRentalReview-g32655-d4751024-West_HOLLYWD_area_FAB-Los_Angeles_California.html'

html_page = requests.get(url).text

urls = re.findall(r'"jumboUrl":"([^"]+)","description":"([^"]+)"', html_page)

print('Length =', len(urls))

for img_url, description in urls:
    print(img_url, description)
```

Prints number of images, their URLs and description:

```
Length = 58
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/00/26/29/8c.jpg Redwood Deck with tables, umbrella, chaise lounges
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/12/01.jpg Living Room
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/11/fd.jpg Living Room
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/11/fe.jpg Living Room
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/11/ff.jpg Living Room
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/12/00.jpg Living Room
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/02/11/12/02.jpg Kitchen
https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/vr-splice-j/00/26/29/1f.jpg Front of duplex
...and so on.
```

Comment: Update your post using a headers `headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}`, otherwise it may not work for all users.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your answer. I've been trying my code using beautifulsoup for 1.5 days haha...glad to know that it doesn't work on dynamic javascript. May I ask you for an example using ```selenium``` if you don't mind?

Comment: Why would you go for any browser simulator when this `requests` and `re` combo is working flawlessly @Todd. Moreover this approach is faster.